# Can a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ have an infinite symmetric group

Tags: group-theory, geometry

After reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478015/groups-in-an-abstract-algebra), I started wondering whether it was possible to have a **bounded path-connected set $S\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ (where $n>1$) with a countably infinite symmetry group $G$**.

---

If you remove bounded, you can take $\left(\Bbb R\times\left\{0\right\}\right)\cup \left(\bigcup\limits_{k\in \Bbb N}\left\{k\right\}\times \Bbb R\right)$, that is, a countable number of parallel lines linked by another line perpendicular to all of them.

If you remove path-connected, you can take the set generated by a point and a rotation around another point with an angle $\alpha$ so that $\cfrac{\alpha}{\pi}\not\in \Bbb Q$.

If you want finitely many elements, you can take the set generated by a point and a rotation around another point with an angle $\alpha$ so that $\cfrac{\alpha}{\pi}\in \Bbb Q$.

If you want uncountably many elements, you can take a circle or the unit ball.

---

I really had no idea how to attack this problem so I tried showing that it was not possible like this (in *italic* are the parts I wouldn't be able to justify or couldn't figure out):

---

Since I have countably many symmetries, I have either countably many rotations or countably many orthogonal symmetries.

If I have uncountably many rotations, it means that I have a rotation of angle $\alpha$ so that $\cfrac{\alpha}{\pi}\not\in \Bbb Q$ and so I have dense subsets of the circles generated by the points in $S$ and this rotation. *Since it is path-connected, it must be that the whole circle is in $S$*. And so $S$ is a union of circles and therefore has an uncountable symmetry group.

I have $\left |S\right|>1$ because otherwise, I have uncountably many symmetries. *And this is where I don't know what to do. I'd like to say that I either have the axes crossing at a given point and then have a dense subset of a circle and hence a circle, or they aren't and then I can build an unbounded set but I didn't manage to transform this intuition into a proof-like argument.*

---

So I ask for your help to finish that proof (or provide another proof or a counterexample).

Comment: Hmm, $\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}} \{t\cdot e^{i\alpha} : t \in [0,1]\}$? That should have symmetry group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}\times \{-1,1\}$, I think.

Comment: Some of your uses of "finite", "countable", and "uncountable" seem inconsistent.

Comment: Well a finite set is countable so I tried to always explicitly say that I didn't want it finite...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I have uncountably many rotations, it means that I have a rotation of angle $\alpha$ so that $\frac \alpha \pi \notin \mathbb{Q}$ and so I have dense subsets of the circles generated by the points in $S$ and this rotation. Since it is path-connected, it must be that the whole circle is in $S$.

This doesn't follow, since there can be other paths that don't stay in the circle.

In fact, just take a disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with radius two and subtract out the set of points on the unit circle with $\frac \alpha \pi \in \mathbb{Q}$.